# How to let Flyout width adjust to application width?

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I use [`Flyouts`](http://mahapps.com/controls/flyouts.html) in my metro style application, which uses the [MahApps Metro package](http://mahapps.com/):

```
<Controls:MetroWindow.Flyouts>
    <Controls:FlyoutsControl>
        <Controls:Flyout Header="INSTELLINGEN" Position="Left" Width="600" Theme="Dark">
            some content
        </Controls:Flyout>
    </Controls:FlyoutsControl>
</Controls:MetroWindow.Flyouts>
```

This works fine, however now I want a `Flyout` that takes up the width of the entire application, even if the user resizes it. Basically I'd like `Width="*"` but this doesn't work.

Comment: What happens if you leave out the `Position` and `Width`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an example that works with the latest alpha version (0.15).

Simply set the `Margin` and `Width` and you get what you need.

```
  <controls:MetroWindow.Flyouts>
    <controls:FlyoutsControl>
      <controls:Flyout Header="INSTELLINGEN"
                       Position="Left"
                       Margin="0 0 100 0"
                       Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=controls:MetroWindow}, Path=ActualWidth}"
                       Theme="Dark">
      </controls:Flyout>
    </controls:FlyoutsControl>
  </controls:MetroWindow.Flyouts>
```

Comment: Good answer. The binding of the width gives me an idea to make my app responsive.